# Jackson ObjectMapper DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I am using Jackson for JSON serialization/deserialization in my Jersey application. I want to read the empty strings in JSON to null value in my java POJO property. I tried to set the DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT on Object Mapper but it is not working. Here is the code below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class TestMapper {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMapper.testJson();

    }

    public static void testJson(){
        String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"First Name\",\"phone\":\"\",\"unknown\":\"test\"}";
        ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
        //result.setDeserializationConfig(result.getDeserializationConfig().with(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT));
        //result.enable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        /*DeserializationConfig deserializeConfig = result.getDeserializationConfig();
        deserializeConfig.with(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);*/
        result.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
        result.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    try {
            TestBean testBean = result.readValue(jsonString, TestBean.class);
            if(testBean.getPhone()!=null&& testBean.getPhone().equals("")){
                System.out.print("Phone Number is empty string");
            }else{
                System.out.print("Phone Number is null");
            }
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The bean is as below

```
public class TestBean {

    private String name;
    private String phone;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public TestBean(String name, String phone) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public TestBean() {
        super();
    }


}
```

The output is always

```
Phone Number is empty string
```

I am not sure why is this not working. I am using Jackson 1.9.2.

Comment: Did u debug it and see what is the value in phone ?

Comment: I am having the same problem, any solution to this? I am using Jackson 1.9

Answer (score 9):

Note the javadoc of [`ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig.Feature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)

> Feature that can be enabled to allow JSON empty String value ("") to be bound to POJOs as null.

So an empty `String` can be used to map `null` to a POJO. A `String` is not a POJO, it is considered a JSON primitive value.

You cannot use that here.

`ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT` would work for something like

```
{"name":"First Name","phone":"","unknown":"test"}
```

Where you would make the `TestBean.phone` field of some POJO type like

```
class Phone {
    private String number;
}
```

Then deserializing would make the `phone` field be `null`.

Comment: IS there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: @user2957698 Not as far as I know. And you probably shouldn't. (Possibly fix your server to return different JSON). Alternatively, after deserialization, you can use a helper function to check if the `String` is empty or `null`.