# Jackson and Bean Validation: Deserialize empty String as null

Tags: jackson, resteasy, bean-validation

I've a RESTeasy application using Jackson and Bean Validation. A POJO might loo like this:

```java
public class Foo {

    @Size(min = 2)
    private String bar;

}
```

Bar is validated if the client sends the bar property. And es expected: If the client does not send the property nothing will be validated.

If the client sends an empty String I'll get a constraint violation. This may be correct but it's hard to control what the value of an empty input field really is. For instance in my angular application the field will not be present if the user did not enter anything. Once he enters and deletes something I'll have an empty String.

I thought I could configure Jacksons behavior via [DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT) but as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22694272) this is only working for POJOs not for Strings. The only ways I see is not using `@Size` or writing an own deserializer for Strings. Both doesn't seem to be good solutions. Anyone other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accept the empty string, you could use the `@Pattern` constraint matching also the empty string: `@Pattern(regexp = "^$|(.){2}")` or `@Pattern(regexp = "^$|..`.

The alternative is to write your [own custom constraint](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints).